# contributes.configuration properties - string types - can you modify the behaviour of the text box in the extensions settings tab?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm working on an extension I have published in the Visual Studio Code marketplace, and I have noticed that the behaviour of the multi-line text box is rendering certain character combinations differently, and I don't want it to do this. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

Specifically, I have a collection of templates (containing code-snippets) displayed as multi-line text boxes with default values, that the user can modify in my extension settings.

I have noticed that HTML closing comments `-->` are being rendered as a solid right-pointing arrow. The actual text hasn't changed, so pulling in the template via vscode.getConfiguration() and using the text works as expected, because the underlying text is as expected. It's just annoying because it doesn't *look* right! It's bugging the life out of me because I cannot find any reference to controlling how a text box behaves.

Out of interest, is this even controlled by Visual Studio Code? Or is it an OS-specific feature of the type of text box that Visual Studio Code happens to use for its setting window? My development environment is Linux - I don't have a Windows machine handy to test out that particular theory. But otherwise it could be easy to find out; just open the settings and enter `-->`  into the first text box (mine is multi-line).

Comment: Anyone able to provide insight itno this issue?

Comment: This is a rare instance where a screenshot would be appropriate (of said text box, etc.).